# switch between Tabs using pushbuttons in pyqt5

Tags: python, button, tabs, pyqt5

I have a GUI that contain three buttons (R1, R2 , R3)

if I clicked on R1, it should take me to R1 page, and so on.

I added this line for the first button to connect it with the first page by using toggle also, but it is not working.

here is the code

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(447, 342)
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(Form)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 451, 341))
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 80, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.tab_2.toggle)

        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 120, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 160, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
        self.tab_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_3.setObjectName("tab_3")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_3, "")
        self.tab_4 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_4.setObjectName("tab_4")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_4, "")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "R1"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Form", "R2"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("Form", "R3"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("Form", "Start page"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("Form", "R1"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_3), _translate("Form", "R2"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_4), _translate("Form", "R3"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QTabWidget.currentIndex : int` - This property holds the index position of the current tab page.

If you need to navigate by clicking a button, use `QTabWidget.setCurrentIndex (int index)`.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(447, 342)
        
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(Form)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 451, 341))
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 80, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

#        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.tab_2.toggle)

        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 120, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 160, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
        self.tab_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_3.setObjectName("tab_3")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_3, "")
        self.tab_4 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_4.setObjectName("tab_4")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_4, "")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "R1"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Form", "R2"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("Form", "R3"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("Form", "Start page"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("Form", "R1"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_3), _translate("Form", "R2"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_4), _translate("Form", "R3"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
     
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(1))   # <---

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: @kikomii  If my answer helped you then do not forget to mark as correct, 
if you do not know how to do it then check the https://stackoverflow.com/tour